# Why react make million request to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here i have a problem which i can't figure out.

i make request to api conditionally like:

```
if ( a != b ) {
   // make here request to api
}
```

first i put my conditions in after `render()` then people are said to me don't use these things in after render.

so i read that it's need to put into `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

And i did it like that

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.loading != this.props.loading) {
     // make here request to api. 
  }
}
```

here is my loading state default false. When **onClick** to button i make it **true** and when request success i turn it to **false**.

So, my requests are stopped to work anytime. They anymore work only when loading state change but again million times..

i don't know what is this. And how stop it.

Comment: We can't help you with code we cannot see. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Use `setTimeout` or similar to emulate the API call.

Comment: Use `componentDidUpdate()` for this.

Basically, what can I defer is, in your `componentWillReceiveProps` you are having an API request, and I am assuming you are setting it somewhere, with setState, which is rerendering the dom and resulting that condition to be called again.